# Optional spaces between multiple layout renderers?

Tags: nlog

I think I must be missing something extremely obvious here but furious doc reading and googling has failed me. I have the following layout for a file name:

```
<target name="asyncLogFile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard" >
      <target name="mainLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/${mdlc:item=GameServer:whenEmpty=Main} ${mdlc:item=Controller}.log"
              layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${message} ${exception:format=toString,Data:maxInnerExceptionLevel=3}" />
    </target>
```

The MDLC items can both be null, in the games of the `GameServer` it gets replaced with "Main" and the `Controller` doesn't matter (If the `GameServer` is null then the `Controller` will be null).

However this means that if `GameServer` is null I end up with

`Main .log` Because of the space I have between the two mdlc entries. How can I make that space optional as part of the `GameServer` mldc entry!? I have looked at `:pad` to add a space after the  but that doesn't seem to work. I have tried concatenating the `mdlc`'s but that doesn't work.

I was expecting something simple you could add as an ambient property like `:suffix` but nothing like that exists.

Again I think I must be missing something basic here but it eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same ugly, but faster because of less allocation:

```xml
    <variable name="GameServerLogFile" value="${when:when='${mdlc:item=GameServer}'=='':inner=Main:else=${mdlc:item=GameServer} ${mdlc:item=Controller}}" />

    <targets>
       <target name="mainLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/${GameServerLogFile}.log" />
    </targets>
```

Better to compare against empty-string `''`, than to call `length()`-method.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but this works

```
<target name="mainLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/${when:when=length('${mdlc:item=GameServer}') > 0:inner=${mdlc:item=GameServer} ${mdlc:item=Controller}:else=Main}.log"
```